# Visual Basic InputBox Wait time

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

Is it possible to Program in VB so that program wait for 10 seconds for user input? If no input entered, Program process with default value after 10 seconds. If yes, then how to program.

Comment: You have to write your own "Inputbox" with a timer (just bild a form). But consider: It may last longer than your timeout, if someone is slow on entering data. so reset the timeout each time a key is pressed.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

In your form code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "closeIfNoValueEntered"
End Sub
```

closing procedure:

```
Sub closeIfNoValueEntered()
    If UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "" Then Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

this procedure must be placed in a separate module, not in userform module .